# How do I Edit this =GOOGLEFINANCE Formula to Return Only the Date into a Single Cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this `googlefinance()` formula, it returns the the date and price side by side into 2 cells, how do I get just the date in a single cell? The formula is in cell D2:

```
=INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "HIGH", B2+1,WORKDAY(B2,10)), 2, 0), 2)
```

Spreadsheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfUDNNV-GBNdU5ashgt8uYTqqJOpAOGhN0I9mM26o_I/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1 to the index function:

```
=INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "HIGH", B2+1,WORKDAY(B2,10)), 2, 0), 2, 1)
```